# How to send direct "Requests from friends" to user from app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, apprequests

I noticed that game **Ravensky City** can send direct requests.

[Example:](http://www.rashka.ru/tmp/rc.png) 
http://www.rashka.ru/tmp/rc.png

Do they have special agreement with FaceBook to do so - or any application can do this?
If so how?

(I read lots of docs and answers today but only got that it's immpossible to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see here is just a regular [Application Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) that can be sent in two ways:

- User to User – by using [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)
- App to User – by [publishing request via Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests)

If you already user of application you'll see this as requests. If you not yet connected with application you'll see request as invitation.